# iOS video recording in chunks

Tags: ios, video, recording, chunks

Is it possible to clip video files while continuos recoding? What I am looking for is say I record a video, I want to send video clips to a server every 5 seconds until the recording is being stopped. For example a video file is recorded for 10 seconds. I want to send 2 video files each of 5 seconds duration. The 1st file is sent while the video continuous to get recorded for the next 5 seconds.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this tutorial:

http://www.ios-developer.net/iphone-ipad-programmer/development/camera/record-video-with-avcapturesession-2

You set up your preview display (if you need one). 
You set up your record/stop button.
When user presses start recording you use

```
[MovieFileOutput startRecordingToOutputFileURL:outputURL recordingDelegate:self];
```

and every X seconds you do:

```
[MovieFileOutput stopRecording];
// setting up the url ...
[MovieFileOutput startRecordingToOutputFileURL:nextOutputURL recordingDelegate:self];
```

Voila! You have a lot of X second files and you can do anything you want with them.

The preview display doesn't show that there was some kind of stop, the same with record buttons.

Comment: Both of these answers leave a tiny bit of missing time between recordings. When assembling the video afterwards, it is not a natural experience. every X seconds has some missing milliseconds..

Answer (score 0):

This is the correct way to record a video in 5 second clips.

Record button is pressed and you start recording the first video clip to a URL.

```
[MovieFileOutput startRecordingToOutputFileURL:outputURL recordingDelegate:self];
```

Set a 5 second timer when the record button is pressed.

```
[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:5.0f target:self selector:@selector(stopRecording) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];

-(void)stopRecording
{
    [MovieFileOutput stopRecording];
}
```

This is where you want to start recording the next video clip. This method is called immediately after the first clip is stopped.

```
- (void)captureOutput:(AVCaptureFileOutput *)captureOutput didFinishRecordingToOutputFileAtURL:(NSURL *)outputFileURL fromConnections:(NSArray *)connections error:(NSError *)error
{
    NSLog(@"end record");
    [MovieFileOutput startRecordingToOutputFileURL:[self getNextURL] recordingDelegate:self];
}
```

Generate a new URL for the next clip.

```
-(NSURL*) getNextURL
{
    videoNumber++;
    NSString *outputPath = [self getTempVideoOutputPath:videoNumber];
    NSURL *outputURL = [[NSURL alloc] initFileURLWithPath:outputPath];

    return outputURL;
}
```

Pass in the clip number to create a new temp URL. For example, this method will create video files clip-1.mov, clip-2.mov, clip-3.mov etc.

```
-(NSString*)getTempVideoOutputPath: (int) clipNumber
{
    //Create temporary URL to record to
    NSString *outputFileName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"clip-%i.mov",clipNumber];
    NSString *outputPath = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%@%@", NSTemporaryDirectory(), outputFileName];

    return outputPath;
}
```

Comment: Both of these answers leave a tiny bit of missing time between recordings. When assembling the video afterwards, it is not a natural experience. every X seconds has some missing milliseconds..